# Grouping dates into Months in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Created the make time below to display biweekly dates

```
<?php
  $date1 = "07/05/2013";
  $date2 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date1 . " + 14 day"));
  $date3 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date2 . " + 14 day"));
  $date4 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date3 . " + 14 day"));
  $date5 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date4 . " + 14 day"));
  $date6 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date5 . " + 14 day"));
  $date7 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date6 . " + 14 day"));
  $date8 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date7 . " + 14 day"));
  $date9 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date8 . " + 14 day"));
  $date10 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date9 . " + 14 day"));
  $date11 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date10 . " + 14 day"));
  $date12 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date11 . " + 14 day"));
  $date13 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date12 . " + 14 day"));
  $date14 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date13 . " + 14 day"));
  $date15 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date14 . " + 14 day"));
  $date16 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date15 . " + 14 day"));
  $date17 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date16 . " + 14 day"));
  $date18 = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date17 . " + 14 day"));
?>
```

How can I get it to group together by Month? Let say I want to know how many dates land in August, or December. Also if I wanted to get how many dates till end of the year? Helping hand will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
// initiate months
$month_arr = Array();
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
    // no. of dates
    $month_arr[$i] = 0;
}
$date_arr = Array();
$date_start = "07/05/2013";
$date_arr[] = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date_start));

for ($i=1; $i<=17; $i++){
    $date_temp = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date_arr[$i-1] . " + 14 day"));
    $month = date('n', strtotime($date_temp));

    $month_arr[$month] += 1;
    $date_arr[] = $date_temp;

  }

 foreach ($month_arr as $k => $v){
    echo "<BR>Month: " . $k . ", No. of dates: " . $v;
 }

// all dates
echo "<BR>All dates<BR>";
var_dump ($date_arr);
?>
```

You can extend this logic to group the actual dates by months rather than getting only the count of dates in a month. This is the solution for that:

```
<?php
// initiate months
$month_arr = Array(
            'January' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()) , 
            'February' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'March' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'April' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'May' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'June' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'July' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'August' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'September' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'October' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'November' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array()), 
            'December' => Array('num_dates'=>0, 'dates'=>Array())
        );
$date_arr = Array();

$date_start = "07/05/2013";
$date_arr[] = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date_start));

for ($i=1; $i<=17; $i++){
    $date_temp = date('M j, Y', strtotime($date_arr[$i-1] . " + 14 day"));
    $month = date('F', strtotime($date_temp));

    $month_arr[$month]['dates'][] = $date_temp;
    $month_arr[$month]['num_dates'] += 1;
    $date_arr[] = $date_temp;
}

foreach ($month_arr as $k => $v){
    if (!empty($v)){
        if ($v['num_dates'] != 0){
            echo "<BR><BR>Month: " . $k;
            echo "<BR>No. of dates: " . $v['num_dates'];
            foreach ($v['dates'] as $k1=>$v1){
                echo "<BR>" . $v1;
            }
        }
     }
}
?>
```

At this point, $month_arr should have everything you need.

Comment: How do I get variable $k1 to carry the amount of dates per month from the second example?

Comment: How would I individualize the results?

Comment: what do mean by individualize the results ? can you give me an example based on your original data ?

Comment: I have to do a calculation to the No. of dates in the month Exp: $count*1250 but I need to do so base on that specific month. Base on the original data $date3, $date4, $date5 would be the month of August in which $count = 3. How do I pull data from the foreach statement to build another IF statement?

Comment: Look at the update that I made to the 2nd part of the answer. In this, month_arr is a multi-dimensional array that has all the values that you need. You can now perform operations on the values on this array now. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33770/discussion-between-zowes-and-maximus2012)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure exactly what you meant about grouping by months
but this will use use an array to declare all the dates and you can change the $limit variable to increase or decrease the amount of dates.
change $dates to adjust your original date
$left is how many days are left in the array (it triggers after the first day is hit, can be changed to trigger on the last day)
and $amount is how many dates are in august

```
<?php
$limit = 17;
$dates = array("07-05-2013");
for ($i=1; $i<=$limit; $i++){
    $dates[$i]=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dates[$i-1] . "+ 14 days"));
}
foreach (array_keys($dates) as $key){ 
    $value = date('m', strtotime($dates[$key])); 
    if ($value == "08"){
        $amount = $amount + 1;  
    }
    if ($amount == 1){
        $left = $limit-$key;
    }
}
print_r ($dates);
echo "<br>";
echo $amount . "<br>" . $left;
?>
```

Comment: might be a bit of a long winded approach, but an answer nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

just add an if statement and increment through all 12 months ... if the months are the same

```
 $n=1;
 $month=array();//dumpyour dates in  an array
 $date=array()

 while($k<30){
 if  (date('n', strtotime($date[$k]))==date('n', strtotime($date[$k-1])){
 echo $date[$k++];
 $m = date('n', strtotime($date[$k]));
 $month[$m]=++$n;
 }
 else{
 .....

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I keep re-iterating on SO, PHP's [DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime) make most datetime operations trivial.

Your question is not 100% clear, but from your comments it seems you want an array of timestamps, 14 days apart sectioned by month. I don't know if you considered that the months may cross year bondaries, but I took that into consideration in my answer.

The code below should do what you want:-

```
$start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '07/05/2013');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P14D');
$periods = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, 26);

$dates = array();

foreach($periods as $day){
    /** @var \DateTime $day */
    $dates[$day->format('Y')][$day->format('M')][] = $day->getTimestamp();
}

var_dump($dates);
```

Output:-

```
array (size=2)
  2013 => 
    array (size=8)
      'May' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1367936286
          1 => int 1369145886
      'Jun' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1370355486
          1 => int 1371565086
      'Jul' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 1372774686
          1 => int 1373984286
          2 => int 1375193886
      'Aug' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1376403486
          1 => int 1377613086
      'Sep' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1378822686
          1 => int 1380032286
      'Oct' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1381241886
          1 => int 1382451486
      'Nov' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1383664686
          1 => int 1384874286
      'Dec' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 1386083886
          1 => int 1387293486
          2 => int 1388503086
  2014 => 
    array (size=5)
      'Jan' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1389712686
          1 => int 1390922286
      'Feb' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1392131886
          1 => int 1393341486
      'Mar' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1394551086
          1 => int 1395760686
      'Apr' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1396966686
          1 => int 1398176286
      'May' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 1399385886
```

I would recommend that, instead of an array of timestamps, you have an array of DateTime objects instead, then you can manipulate each one as you wish. In which case, the code would look like this:-

```
$start = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '07/05/2013');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P14D');
$periods = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, 26);

$dates = array();

foreach($periods as $day){
    /** @var \DateTime $day */
    $dates[$day->format('Y')][$day->format('M')][] = $day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$months=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$years=array('2010','20111','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018');
$dates = array('2015-04-24','2015-04-28','2017-03-24', '2017-03-24', '2017-04-07', '2017-04-14', '2017-04-21', '2017-04-28');
$result=array();
foreach ($months as $mn) {
foreach ($years as $year) {
$r=array();
foreach ($dates as $month) {
if(date_parse_from_format("Y.n.j", $year) 
["year"]==date_parse_from_format("Y.n.j", $month)["year"] && 
date_parse_from_format("Y.n.j", $month)["month"]==$mn){$r[]=$month;}
;}
if(empty($r)){;}else{$result[]=$r;};
;}
;};
var_dump($result);
```

this code should work, and it will segment according to year and month, please add more years to the $years variable as needed and your dates to the $dates array, note that duplicate values will be eliminated and if you prefer to keep duplicates just add a random letter to the end of each date when you insert it into an array as a key and then delete the extra letter when processing is finished.